# Объединение MessageBox с QTextEdit и QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt5

Подскажите можно ли вывести `MessageBox`, который бы содержал в себе `QTextEdit` и `QComboBox`?

Если  да, то как потом мне обрабатывать полученные от пользователя данные?

Comment: Проще создать модальное окно с необходимыми виджетами. Ловите событие закрытия этого окна, записываете в переменные данные из edit и combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, нет. Создавай для этого отдельный виджет.